# Не читает русские символы в задаче

Tags: python

Есть олимпиадная задача:
Петя и Вася обмениваются шифрованными сообщениями. Они используют такой алгоритм шифрования. Берут секретное число k, известное на всём свете только им двоим, и в каждом слове сообщения k раз первую букву переставляют в конец слова. Например, если k=3, то слово «ШКОЛА» превратится сначала в «КОЛАШ», затем в «ОЛАШК» и, наконец, в «ЛАШКО». После этого полученное слово записывают в обратном порядке: «ОКШАЛ». Такое шифрование – довольно тяжёлый труд, помогите Пете и Васе его автоматизировать. 
Я ее решил  и в python'e работает все нормально,но на сайте где проверяет,ставит 0 баллов
вот код решения:

```
a=int(input())
b=str(input()).upper()
n=0
spis=[]
for i in b:
spis.append(i)
while n<a:
  n=n+1
  spis.append(spis.pop(0))
print(*spis[::-1], sep='')
```

что сделать чтобы читало русские символы??решите эту проблему пожалуйста а то обидно решил же ее

Comment: 1) `>> что сделать чтобы читало русские символы` оно уже читает их. 2) `str(input()).upper()` можно заменить на `input().upper()` у вас ведь питон3 используется? 3) Кст, а вы уверены, что нужно всегда в верхний регистр переводить? В условии нет ничего про это

Comment: А немножко подумать, прежде чем писать программу "влоб"? *Например, если k=3, то слово «ШКОЛА»* Длина слова 5, число 3. Берём слово, повторяем `roundup(1+(3/5))=2` раз, получаем «ШКОЛАШКОЛА». Берём 5 букв после 3-й, получаем «ЛАШКО». Всё.

Comment: А зачем вообще нужен upper? Что-то я не вижу такого в задании

Comment: @gil9red нужен там upper там во входных данных требуется

Comment: @ДОБРЫЙДЕДУШКА, ничего нет в условиях задачи про это верхний регистр, то, что пример входных данных в верхнем регистре, не значит, что и остальные будут в нем

Comment: @gil9red вы мне скажите лучше как проблему решить

Comment: @ДОБРЫЙДЕДУШКА, алгоритм правильный... а как вы поняли, что проблема с русскими символами? У вас на том сайте кракозябры выводит? Возможно, вам нужно обратиться к преподавателю сайта (или к администрации). Кст, вы ведь не на stepic'е проходите задание?

Comment: @gil9red ну да на сайте)

Comment: @ДОБРЫЙДЕДУШКА, а скиньте ссылку на само задание

Comment: @gil9red http://timus-offline.net/problem.aspx?space=764&num=4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k = int(input())
s = input()

print(''.join(s[k % len(s):] + s[:k % len(s)])[::-1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте без перевода в верхний регистр, плюс сделал небольшой рефакторинг:

```
n = int(input())
text = input()

items = list(text)
for _ in range(n):
    items.append(items.pop(0))
print(*items[::-1], sep='')
```

Comment: нет,не помогло у меня почему то на проверяющем сайте не читает русские символы